# I get an error when i try and publish posts when the user is not signed in in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, sql, authentication, laravel-5

I am creating a blog, however when the user is signed in meaning they are authenticated, i can see the posts in my dashboard, however, when i signed out and redirected to the dashboard i get an error saying "Trying to get property of non-object ........"

below is my code

```
public function getDashboard() {
      $posts = Post::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();
      return view('welcome, [
              'posts' => $posts,
              'user' => Auth::user()
      ]);
}

 @foreach($posts as $post)
            <div class="post-preview" data-postid="{{ $post->id }}">
                <a href="#">
                    <h2 class="post-title">
                        {{ $post->header }}
                    </h2>
                    <h3 class="post-subtitle">
                        {{ $post->body }}
                    </h3>
                </a>
                <p class="post-meta">Posted by <a href="#">{{ $post->user->username }}</a> on {{ $post->created_at }}</p>
            </div>
            <hr>
            @endforeach
```

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: Don't truncate the error message, you left out the most important part to locate it

Comment: Did you refer to your user object in your view? 'user' => Auth::user() looks like what causes it if you're not logged in

Comment: @SteD Yes i am using the user object as shown in the code to show the user who posted the post. like '{{ $post->user->username }}' and i am sure the Auth::user() is what's causing the porblem. Howver im not sure of how to solve it

Answer (score 0):

You just need to check if user is logged in

in template file:

```
@if($user)
    @foreach($posts as $post)
        <div class="post-preview" data-postid="{{ $post->id }}">
            <a href="#">
                <h2 class="post-title">
                    {{ $post->header }}
                </h2>
                <h3 class="post-subtitle">
                    {{ $post->body }}
                </h3>
            </a>
            <p class="post-meta">Posted by <a href="#">{{ $post->user->username }}</a> on {{ $post->created_at }}</p>
        </div>
        <hr>
    @endforeach
@endif
```

or in controller file:

```
public function getDashboard() {
      $posts = Post::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();
      return view('welcome', [
              'posts' => (Auth::user()) ? $posts : [],
              'user' => Auth::user()
      ]);
}
```

Comment: That didnt solve it. I want unauthorised users to also see the posts

Comment: That's wrong, if $post is an array you can't access it as an object.

Comment: @DamienPirsy if $post is an empty array the loop will be not executed, so this code works also fine: `foreach([] as $a) echo $a->b;` (without any errors)